# Set default value of reactive form once observable returns

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have some code ngOnInit that uses a routing variable to filter an observable array for a specific object:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => { // Wrapper to get route param (ID)

  this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadObjects());
  this.object$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllObjects).pipe(
    map(
      objects => objects.filter(o => o.id === params.get('id'))[0]
    )
  );

})
```

Then I have the following to initialize a form:

```
this.objectDataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'name':     ['', Validators.required ],
  'location': ['', Validators.required ]
});
```

I want to somehow connect my observable object to the form data to bring in as a default value. I think I need patchValue:

```
this.objectDataForm.patchValue({
  name: myValue1, 
  location: myValue2
});
```

But I cannot figure out how to put this patch value in a place where it gets the value at the right time and delivers it to the form. I could easily be nuking this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `take(1)` operator. See [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html).

The flow would be:

- create a subscription from your `object$.pipe(take(1))` stream
- inside subscription, call `patchValue`
- *Note:* you may want to call `.patchValue({ ... }, { emitEvent: false })` if you wish to skip this initial setup when subscribing to form's `valueChanges` stream

Comment: I have been working on this for more than 5 hours today. Finally got it working! Thank you.